# Debian package issue: files are installing into '/'

Tags: ubuntu, debian, compiling, packaging

I have been recently trying to package a small Python utility to put on my PPA and I've almost got it to work, but I'm having problems in making the package install the binary (a chmod +x Python script) under `/usr/bin`. Instead it installs under `/`. I have this directory structure -> http://db.tt/0KhIYQL.

My package Makefile is like so:

```
TARGET=usr/bin/txtrevise

make:
      chmod +x $(TARGET)

install:
      cp -r $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)
```

I've used `$(DESTDIR)`, as I understand it to place the file under the debian subdir when debuild is run.

I have the txtrevise script, my executable, under `usr/bin` folder under the root of my package. I also have the Makefile and `usr/bin/textrevise` in my tarball: txtrevise_1.1.original.tar.gz.

However when I build this and look inside of the Debian package, txtrevise is always at the root of the package instead of under usr/bin and will be installed to / instead of /usr/bin.

How can I get debuild to put the script in the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `cp $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)` invocation: this will
copy the file `textrevise` under directory `$(DESTDIR)`, i.e. skips
the `/usr/bin` prefix.  You need to preserve the directory structure,
so for instance:

```
install:
    # ensure the destination directory exists
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin
    # copy the program to its final destination
    cp $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)/$(TARGET)
    # ensure the program and directories have the correct permissions
    chmod a+rx $(DESTDIR)/$(TARGET)
```

Note that you must also ensure, when building a software package for
others to use, that the permissions an all directories and binaries
are set according to the [Debian policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/); in this case you want
`$(DESTDIR)/usr/bin/textrevise` to be owned by `root:root` and mode
`0755` (and so the directories `$(DESTDIR)/usr` and
`$(DESTDIR)/usr/bin`).

You might want to have a look at the
[install](http://linux.die.net/man/1/install) command, that gives you
more control over the owner, group and mode of the installed files to
write more concise Makefile stanzas.

Comment: Why not fold the use of `install` into your example (and remove the `cp`)?